# no microphone exist on a brand new Inspiron 5509

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I am trying to use the onboard microphone for video conferencing. I have no microphone adjustment in alsamixer or pavucontrol.

I'm sure this laptop has a microphone, I just can't see it. It's acting just like a driver issue but I can't find model information to start chasing drivers.

installed drivers:

```
root@NewInspiron15:/home/# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
rfcomm                 81920  4
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  8
algif_hash             16384  3
algif_skcipher         16384  3
af_alg                 28672  14 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   24576  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
usbhid                 57344  0
cp210x                 36864  0
usbserial              53248  1 cp210x
cdc_ether              20480  0
usbnet                 49152  1 cdc_ether
r8152                  77824  0
mii                    20480  2 usbnet,r8152
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
btusb                  57344  0
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
videobuf2_common       57344  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                28672  1 btusb
videodev              241664  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
bluetooth             581632  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
mc                     57344  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    32768  1 ecdh_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
mei_hdcp               24576  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   131072  1
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_sof_pci            24576  0
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    77824  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               122880  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    45056  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
snd_soc_core          270336  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
snd_hda_intel          53248  4
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         139264  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           94208  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               114688  10 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
dell_laptop            24576  0
joydev                 24576  0
kvm_intel             286720  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof,dell_laptop
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
iwlmvm                393216  0
dell_smm_hwmon         20480  0
kvm                   712704  1 kvm_intel
mac80211              905216  1 iwlmvm
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
aesni_intel           372736  15
snd_seq                69632  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
dell_wmi               20480  0
cryptd                 24576  5 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
i915                 2199552  50
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
input_leds             16384  0
dcdbas                 20480  1 dell_smbios
iwlwifi               352256  1 iwlmvm
drm_kms_helper        217088  1 i915
snd                    94208  20 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
serio_raw              20480  0
mei_me                 40960  1
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mei                   106496  3 mei_hdcp,mei_me
efi_pstore             16384  0
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
soundcore              16384  1 snd
rc_core                57344  1 cec
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
cfg80211              778240  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
processor_thermal_device    24576  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
intel_rapl_common      28672  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
typec_ucsi             32768  1 ucsi_acpi
hid_multitouch         28672  0
cros_ec_ishtp          20480  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cros_ec                20480  1 cros_ec_ishtp
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 processor_thermal_device
typec                  53248  1 typec_ucsi
mac_hid                16384  0
soc_button_array       20480  0
int3403_thermal        20480  0
int340x_thermal_zone    20480  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
int3400_thermal        20480  0
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
intel_hid              20480  0
acpi_pad              184320  0
sparse_keymap          16384  2 intel_hid,dell_wmi
acpi_tad               16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
parport_pc             45056  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
drm                   552960  19 drm_kms_helper,i915
parport                65536  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               49152  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
uas                    28672  1
usb_storage            73728  1 uas
hid_sensor_custom      24576  0
hid_sensor_hub         24576  1 hid_sensor_custom
intel_ishtp_loader     24576  0
intel_ishtp_hid        24576  0
hid_generic            16384  0
nvme                   45056  1
nvme_core             110592  3 nvme
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
psmouse               155648  0
i2c_i801               32768  0
intel_lpss_pci         20480  0
thunderbolt           196608  0
intel_lpss             16384  1 intel_lpss_pci
intel_ish_ipc          24576  0
i2c_smbus              20480  1 i2c_i801
idma64                 20480  0
xhci_pci               20480  0
intel_ishtp            53248  4 cros_ec_ishtp,intel_ishtp_hid,intel_ish_ipc,intel_ishtp_loader
virt_dma               20480  1 idma64
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
vmd                    16384  0
wmi                    32768  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
i2c_hid                28672  0
hid                   135168  6 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_sensor_hub,intel_ishtp_hid,hid_generic
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
pinctrl_tigerlake      32768  1
pinctrl_intel          28672  1 pinctrl_tigerlake
```

How do I turn on the microphone on a brand new Inspiron 5509?

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

But that did not help. Neither did looking in audacity.

UPDATE:

```
arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3204 Analog [ALC3204 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC3204 Alt Analog [ALC3204 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

UPDATE 2:

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
```

my alsamixer output for the microphone is peculiar.

[image]

debug output:

```
NewInspiron15:~$ sudo alsa force-reload
[sudo] password for brad: 
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-sof-pci snd-sof-intel-byt snd-sof-intel-ipc snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-sof-pci snd-sof-intel-byt snd-sof-intel-ipc snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
```

UPDATE:

```
NewInspiron15:~$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3204 Analog [ALC3204 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC3204 Alt Analog [ALC3204 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
NewInspiron15:~$ arecord -f S16_LE -d 10 -r 16000 --device="hw:0,0" /tmp/test-mic.wav
Recording WAVE '/tmp/test-mic.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 16000 Hz, Mono
arecord: set_params:1374: Channels count non available
```

The above creates no sound file.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336087/18-04-issues-with-x1-carbon-alsamixer-config-microphone-issues-what-does-pa

Comment: @Raffa I added load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,6 to /etc/pulse/default.pa and still nothing.

Comment: Test it first… run in the terminal `pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,6` and see if you get a microphone under sound in settings. If not, please add the output of `arecord -l` to your questions.

Comment: @Raffa I added the output. I still get nothing after reboot.

Comment: Please try again replacing `device=hw:0,6` with the numbers of the two devices in your output... ie.  first try with `device=hw:0,0` and if that did not work try with the second device `device=hw:0,2`... Please also add your Ubuntu version and is it an upgrade or fresh install... did the mic work before?... Please also go through the troubleshooting steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640/968501)

Comment: Your card is relatively new and support for it is still incomplete / missing in some Linux kernels... So newer kernels might bring full support in the future... please see this similar post from another site: https://www.linux.org/threads/new-hardware-new-luck.27780/

Comment: @Raffa I updated the post with the version 20.04.2 LTS. This is the first time I have needed the microphone so I assume it never worked. Install is about 1 month old. I'm not getting any luck with the troubleshooting steps provided. I am posting that output as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124090/discussion-between-brad-and-raffa).

Comment: @Raffa I still get nothing

Comment: @Raffa Bump. Still looking for a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it. Specifically his second update.

[Fix url](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1213271/microphone-does-not-work-on-new-dell-inspiron-7590)

```
gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

add
blacklist snd-hda-intel
blacklist snd-soc-skl

reboot
```